# Blocking YouTube Android app from router

Tags: wireless-router, android, youtube, blocking

I was wondering, how can I block the YouTube Android app from the router itself?

My router (TP-Link TL-WR940N) has a function to block a web address or an IP address.

So does anyone know what website/IP address should I block to make the YouTube app not able to connect?

Comment: I doubt this is possible to block a specific app's communication, unless you block www.youtube.com period from the router.

Comment: Are you trying to block all youtube traffic, or just the mobile app?

Comment: Have you tried just blocking "*.youtube.com/*"?

Comment: You need to add youtubekids.com, www.youtubekids.com and probably other subdomains associated with the parent domain. My kids were watching this the other day and I feel the videos were misleading, disturbing and inappropriate. I am trying to divert the kids to the excellent educative free to air TV which I am confident is regulated appropriately.

Answer (score 15):

Adding to the previous list, the best way I've found to block YouTube content from desktop/laptop computers, iOS, and Android apps is by blocking the following list of URLs on your router/firewall:

- `youtube.com`
- `www.youtube.com`
- `m.youtube.com`
- `ytimg.com`
- `s.ytimg.com`
- `ytimg.l.google.com`
- `youtube.l.google.com`
- `i.google.com`
- `googlevideo.com`
- `youtu.be`
- `yt.be`

This should block all access on Macs/PCs. Mobile apps will still launch, and perhaps display some UI, but the videos themselves should be suppressed.

Comment: I tried this, seems to work... I registered for free OpenDNS account and block the urls from there.

Comment: This blocks on the PC browser but not on iphone (app, safari)

Comment: This doesn't work. I assume the app uses direct IP connections. Might be able to figure out what it is with Wireshark.

Answer (score 5):

You can block Youtube by blocking below URLs:

- youtube.com
- m.youtube.com
- youtu.be
- ytimg.com

[image]

Comment: This blocks youtube in the browser but not in the android app. I tried and the app is still working

Answer (score 4):

Try to block these sites in your router: `googlevideo.com`, `l.google.com`.

Other YouTube domains, you might consider blocing also includes: `youtube.com`, `m.youtube.com`, `youtu.be`, `ytimg.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following list in the router blocked list and worked on Windows/Apple devices. Possibly work on Android, but didn't check:

```
youtube.com
youtube-nocookie.com
youtu.be
ytimg.com
ggpht.com
googleapis.com
googlevideo.com
m.youtube.com
s.ytimg.com
ytimg.l.google.com
youtube.l.google.com
i.google.com
yt.be
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't (be bothered to) pinpoint which one did the trick, but having this list blocks Youtube on my android

- YouTube.com
- googleapis.com
- youtu.be
- youtube.com
- youtube.l.google.com
- youtubei.googleapis.com
- yt.be
- ytimg.com